# User Controls in Windows Forms - Anything similar to ASP.NET User Controls?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

In ASP.NET you have something called "User Controls", which allow you to design a custom control which can be reused in the website.

I am now starting developing a Windows application in .NET 2.0 and (surprisingly) I cannot find a similar functionality.

What I would like to do is:
- Create a new user control in the designer;
- Drag & Drop a few controls on it (e.g. buttons, textboxes);
- Save, and be able to resuse this user controls by dragging and dropping it on various dialogs.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Giammarco Schisani

Answer (score 5):

[UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)

Step-by-step guide to create, add and use UserControls in WinForms applications: http://www.devcity.net/Articles/87/ssteps_customcontrol.aspx

Main steps are:

- Create a library project
- Add or customize the default UserControl
- Build the project
- Add a new windows application project
- Open the Form in the designer: your new control appears.

Comment: +1 : Just the right link, was always well awarded in expertsExchange, I remember.  At SOF this beheviour still have to kick in a bit more

Comment: Ehem...refresh before comment pls

Comment: @Peter: There are philosophic reasons behind this behavior. This place is going to be Wikipedia in programming field. It's more community-oriented than *solve the guy's problem and go*.

Comment: @boj, thank you, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this using the designer, as we do in ASP.NET.

Comment: May I misunderstood something but which steps are missing in WinForms?

- Create a new user control in the designer (works, in the same project too)
- Drag & Drop a few controls on it (works)
- Save, and be able to resuse this user controls by dragging and dropping it on various dialogs (works)